# Entity framework saving context

Tags: entity-framework, save

```
public static TraffickingToScheduled CreateTraffickingToScheduled(int ScheduledID, global::System.DateTime startDate, global::System.DateTime endDate, int originatingNetworkID, int showID, int seasonID, int episodeID, string ffDisable)
{
    TraffickingToScheduled traffickingToScheduled = new TraffickingToScheduled();
    traffickingToScheduled.ScheduledID = ScheduledID;
    traffickingToScheduled.StartDate = startDate;
    traffickingToScheduled.EndDate = endDate;
    traffickingToScheduled.OriginatingNetworkID = originatingNetworkID;
    traffickingToScheduled.ShowID = showID;
    traffickingToScheduled.SeasonID = seasonID;
    traffickingToScheduled.EpisodeID = episodeID;
    traffickingToScheduled.FFDisable = ffDisable;
    return traffickingToScheduled;
}
Context.AddToTraffickingToScheduleds(traffickingToScheduled);
Save();
```

I have a foreign reference with `Scheduled` table to `TraffickingToScheduled` table with 1 to 1 relationship. while saving it throws the error as `TraffickingToScheduled` participate in `TraffickingToScheduled_FK_Scheduled` relationship. 0 related "Scheduled" is found.1 `Scheduled` is expected.